# Some parts of my query are being encoded into different words

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

So I have this PHP function that contains a query to select data from postgresql database

```
public function checkEkspedisi2($resi_no, $shipper)
  {
    $return = array();
    $conn = new PDO(DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
    $sql = "SELECT resi_no FROM t_vbak WHERE resi_no = '$resi_no' ";
    if ($shipper == "J&T") {
      $sql .= " AND (UPPER(REPLACE(shipper,' ','')) LIKE ('%" . strtoupper(trim($shipper)) . "%')) AND (UPPER(REPLACE(shipper,' ','')) NOT LIKE UPPER('%Cargo%')) ";
    } else {
      $sql .= " AND UPPER(REPLACE(shipper,' ','')) LIKE('%" . strtoupper(trim($shipper)) . "%') ";
    }
    echo $sql;
    die();
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
      while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $return[] = $row;
      }
    }
    $stmt = null;
    $conn = null;
    return $return;
  }
```

This specific part below change from `UPPER('%Cargo%')` to `UPPER('Êrgo%')` when I echo the query.

My code :

```
AND (UPPER(REPLACE(shipper,' ','')) LIKE ('%" . strtoupper(trim($shipper)) . "%')) AND (UPPER(REPLACE(shipper,' ','')) NOT LIKE UPPER('%Cargo%'))
```

echo result :

```
AND (UPPER(REPLACE(shipper,' ','')) LIKE ('%J&T%')) AND (UPPER(REPLACE(shipper,' ','')) LIKE UPPER('Êrgo%'))
```

I've tried wrapping it using `urlencode` function in php but the result of the query is different from the database. When i manually query it from pgAdmin the result is correct, but the result from the PHP function (using `urlencode`) returns a different value (wrong)

Comment: Did you decode urlencode ?

Comment: Even though the "echo" is wrong, the query string is correct.  Somehow, you are seeing URL encoding of the string `%CA`, but the string should still have those characters.

Comment: This code is incredibly vulnerable to [SQL Injection attacks](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection), please use [bound parameters](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) instead of interpolating user-data into a query string

Comment: @TimRoberts if the string still has those characters then the return value should be correct. But it did not i don't understand why

Comment: Something's missing here. There's no way URL encoding/decoding can happen in this context. On a side note, it's very strange that you're taking the work of using a prepared statement, but you complete avoid binding parameters.

Comment: @CerebralFart Yes I'm normally using bind parameters but I currently remove it so I can easily debug the function/query

Comment: What is the encoding of your file? UTF8?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved!

I change this :

```
UPPER('%Cargo%'))
```

Into this :

```
UPPER('%'||'Cargo'||'%'))
```

Comment: Both statements are equivalent from SQL standpoint. PostgreSQL does not treat string literals as URLs: https://dbfiddle.uk/qstOnoGJ